# What frequency (color) of visible light do human's emit as bioluminescence?

Tags: visible-light

I've [been reading](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0006256) about human visible light bioluminescence. I dug in but couldn't find where it states what frequency(s) within the visible spectrum this light was. Does anyone know?

Comment: From the paper: "The spectra of photon emission detected from the palm skin span from 500 to 700 nm, with primary and secondary emission peaks at 630–670 nm and 520–580 nm, respectively". It's in the second-to-last paragraph of the Results and Discussion section.

Comment: Ok thankyou. It's a shame they didn't tell us the emissions from the face since "photon emission intensity from the face was higher than from the body". Also we can't calculate an exact color, even of the palms since they didn't give us the exact relative values of those primary/secondary emissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @march for finding the info, I could extend this by calculating a rough estimate of the color of the light emanating from the palms. Picking 640nm (red) as the primary emission and 550 (green) as the secondary, and assuming primary emissions are double in intensity to the secondary, we get a kind of [brown/gold](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/light/Lesson-2/Color-Addition) color (dependant on exposure).